# Report *only* mouse wheel events in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, iterm

In *Preferences* -> *Profiles* -> *Terminal*, my iTerm2 (3.2.7beta4) has the following options:

[image: Enable mouse reporting]

I would like iTerm2 to send mouse wheel events to the application (so that I can e.g. scroll in tmux), but **not** other mouse events. When I use mouse to select text (without any modifier keys), I want iTerm2 to handle that, not tmux. It looks like I can't do that with the above options. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it right know, but [this pull request](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/pull/392), if it gets accepted, will enable iTerm2 to report mouse wheel events without reporting clicks.